# How can i pass values in a modal in bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to complete the project today but i figured it out that the edit function which i wrote was not working as every button i click on the edit it displays the same values. I needed to show the respective data to display in one particular modal.

Here is what i had done:

```
<?php 
 foreach ($allhealthlist as $row):

   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['HI Name'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['Ownership'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['District'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['VDC'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['Type'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>';
?> 


<div class="col-md-1">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">

           <div class="modal-header">
             <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Heath Institute</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">

             <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Edit Information </strong></h3></div>
               <div class="panel-body">



                <form role="form">
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="hide">ID</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control hide" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="healtid" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">HI Name</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="healthname" value="<?php echo $row['HI Name']; ?>">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Ownership</label>
                   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="ownership" value="<?php echo $row['HI Name']; ?>">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">District</label>
                   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="district" value="<?php echo $row['HI Name']; ?>">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">VDC</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="vdc" value="<?php echo $row['HI Name']; ?>">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Type</label>
                   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="type" value="<?php echo $row['HI Name']; ?>">
                 </div>

              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dalog -->
       </div><!-- /.modal -->
       <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</a>
      </div>

 <?php
  echo '</td>';
  endforeach;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion better is to save your data in JavaScript object, then when you open Modal you can set those values where you want.